# Python erroneous logic

Tags: python, multithreading, raspberry-pi3

I am new to Python and trying to understand where my logic is wrong. I am creating a project which controls a hydroponic setup. I have a fogger, a heat lamp and one oxygen machine. The power or on is controlled by relays and the sensors also have their controllers. I can pretty much control the appliances as I want but now when I realized that I must start using threads to get the last pieces on place, my logic seems to be failing. It does not behave as I expected.

The setup is a Raspbian on a Raspberry Pi 3. I have a LCD (16x2) where I wish to print useful data without having the screen on all the time and as mentioned the machinery, sensors and relays.

What I do wish to accomplish is this; I have three processes (one for the fogger, one for the heat lamp and one for the oxygen) and they must each run on a thread. Data from the sensors will be shown on the LCD.

My plan is for a perpetual run unless a kill switch is engaged (two buttons must be pressed at the same time and then the kill switch flag will be set to True. This is something I have not yet implemented but the plan is that when this flag is set the sensors and all should stop their work and gracefully die. This kill switch is when I need to change the water or something like that). While the run is going, the threads are doing their job and displaying their data on the LCD with some interval. I.e first the fogger is displaying the temperature from the sensor for four seconds, then the next set of sensors display their sensor data for four seconds etc. This repetitive cycle should go on forever.

What changes must I do to make the logic behave as I expect it to? The logic in its entirety is down below. As it is right now the cycles are off, the relay turns on and off sporadically and the LCD displays data arbitrarily and sometimes even strange characters (interference?).

```
# Control program

# Source: rplcd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/getting_started.html
#         https://www.circuitbasics.com/raspberry-pi-lcd-set-up-and-programming-in-python/

# LCD            R Pi                

# RS             GPIO 26 (pin 37)        
# E              GPIO 19 (35)
# DB4            GPIO 13 (33)
# DB5            GPIO 6  (31)
# DB6            GPIO 5  (29)
# DB7            GPIO 11 / SCLK (23)

# WPSE311/DHT11  GPIO 24 (18) 

# Relay          GPIO 21 (40)


# Imports--- [ToDo: How to import settings from a configuration file?]
import adafruit_dht, board, digitalio, threading 
import adafruit_character_lcd.character_lcd as characterlcd
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from time import sleep, perf_counter
from datetime import datetime


# Compatible with all versions of RPI as of Jan. 2019
# v1 - v3B+
lcd_rs = digitalio.DigitalInOut(board.D26)
lcd_en = digitalio.DigitalInOut(board.D19)
lcd_d4 = digitalio.DigitalInOut(board.D13)
lcd_d5 = digitalio.DigitalInOut(board.D6)
lcd_d6 = digitalio.DigitalInOut(board.D5)
lcd_d7 = digitalio.DigitalInOut(board.D11)


# Define LCD column and row size for 16x2 LCD.
lcd_columns = 16
lcd_rows    = 2

# Initialise the lcd class---
lcd = characterlcd.Character_LCD_Mono(lcd_rs, lcd_en, lcd_d4, lcd_d5, lcd_d6,
                                      lcd_d7, lcd_columns, lcd_rows)

GPIO.setwarnings(False)

# Init sensors---
dhtDevice_nutrient_mist = adafruit_dht.DHT11(board.D24, use_pulseio=False)
#dhtDevice_xx = adafruit_dht.DHT22(board.Dxx, use_pulseio=False)
#dhtDevice = adafruit_dht.DHT11(board.D24, use_pulseio=False)


# Define relays
relay_fogger = 21 #digitalio.DigitalInOut(board.D21) #- Why does this not work?
#relay_heatlamp = xx
#relay_oxygen = xx


# Init relays---
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setup(relay_fogger, GPIO.OUT)


# Define liquid nutrient temperature probe
liquid_nutrients_probe = 16 #digitalio.DigitalInOut(board.D16) - Why does this not work?


# Global variables---
temp_nutrient_solution = 0
temp_nutrient_mist = 0
humidity_nutrient_mist = 0
temp_roots = 0
humidity_roots = 0
fogger_on_seconds = 2700 #45 min
fogger_off_seconds = 900 #15 min
killswitch = False


# Methods---
def get_temp_nutrient_solution():
    """Measure the temperature of the nutrients solution where the ultrasonic fogger is."""
    lcd.clear()
    lcd.home()
    lcd.message = datetime.now().strftime('%b %d  %H:%M:%S\n')

def get_temp_humidity_nutrient_mist():
    """Measure the humidity of the nutrient mist where the ultrasonic fogger is."""
    lcd.clear()
    lcd.home()
    try:
        # Print the values to the lcd
        temperature_c = dhtDevice_nutrient_mist.temperature
        temperature_f = temperature_c * (9 / 5) + 32
        humidity = dhtDevice_nutrient_mist.humidity
        
        temp_nutrient_mist = temperature_c
        humidity_nutrient_mist = humidity       
                        
        lcd.message = (
            "T: {:.1f}C / {:.1f}F \nHumidity: {}% ".format(
                temperature_c, temperature_f, humidity
            )
        )
        
        # For development process
        print(
            "T: {:.1f} C / {:.1f} F Humidity: {}% ".format(
                temperature_c, temperature_f, humidity
            )
        )
 
    except RuntimeError as error:
        # Errors happen fairly often, DHT's are hard to read, just keep going
        print(error.args[0])
        sleep(1) # sleep(1) for DHT11 and sleep(2) for DHT22
        pass
    except Exception as error:
        dhtDevice.exit()
        raise error
 
    sleep(1)

def get_temp_():
    """Measure the temperature of..."""
    lcd.message = 'Test'

def relay_fogger_control():
    """Fogger on for 45 min and off for 15. Perpetual mode unless kill_processes() is activated"""
    GPIO.output(relay_fogger, GPIO.HIGH)
    sleep(1)
    #sleep(fogger_on_seconds)
    GPIO.output(relay_fogger, GPIO.LOW)
    sleep(1)
    #sleep(fogger_off_seconds)

def relay_heatLED_control():
    """Heat LED controller. When is it too hot for the crops? Sleep interval? Perpetual mode unless kill_processes() is activated"""


def relay_oxygen_control():
    """Oxygen maker. Perpetual mode unless kill_processes() is activated"""


def kill_processes():
    """ToDo: Two push buttons (must be pressed simultaneously) which gracefully kills all processes preparing for shutdown."""
    # Do something
    # Joined the threads / stop the threads after killswitch is true
    t1.join()
    t2.join()
    t3.join()
    t4.join()
    
    lcd.clear()
    lcd.home()
    # Call something that cleans everything up
    lcd.message = 'Full stop.\r\nSafe to remove.'
    GPIO.cleanup()


# Created the Threads
t1 = threading.Thread(target=get_temp_nutrient_solution)
t2 = threading.Thread(target=get_temp_nutrient_solution)
t3 = threading.Thread(target=get_temp_humidity_nutrient_mist)
t4 = threading.Thread(target=relay_fogger_control)
 
# Started the threads
t1.start()
t2.start()
t3.start()
t4.start()


# Code main process--- What to do now?
while not killswitch:
    relay_fogger_control()
    get_temp_nutrient_solution()
    get_temp_humidity_nutrient_mist()
    #sleep(20) #sleep 60 sec? sleep(60)
    #killswitch = True

# Graceful exit
kill_processes()
```

After getting excellent suggestions from SO users I have updated the code to look like below. My new code has a logical error somewhere but since my question with this thread has been answered I consider this issue solved and will post a new question. I decided to go with one button finally and hope that the code below helps someone else.

```
# Source: rplcd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/getting_started.html
#         https://www.circuitbasics.com/raspberry-pi-lcd-set-up-and-programming-in-python/

# LCD            R Pi                

# RS             GPIO 26 (pin 37)        
# E              GPIO 19 (35)
# DB4            GPIO 13 (33)
# DB5            GPIO 6  (31)
# DB6            GPIO 5  (29)
# DB7            GPIO 11 / SCLK (23)

# WPSE311/DHT11  GPIO 24 (18) 

# Relay Fog      GPIO 21 (40)
# Relay Oxy      GPIO 20 (38)
# Relay LED      GPIO 16 (36)

# Button Killsw. GPIO 12 (32)


# Imports--- [ToDo: How to import settings from a configuration file?]
import adafruit_dht, board, digitalio, threading 
import adafruit_character_lcd.character_lcd as characterlcd
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from time import sleep, perf_counter
from gpiozero import CPUTemperature
from datetime import datetime

# Compatible with all versions of RPI as of Jan. 2019
# v1 - v3B+
lcd_rs = digitalio.DigitalInOut(board.D26)
lcd_en = digitalio.DigitalInOut(board.D19)
lcd_d4 = digitalio.DigitalInOut(board.D13)
lcd_d5 = digitalio.DigitalInOut(board.D6)
lcd_d6 = digitalio.DigitalInOut(board.D5)
lcd_d7 = digitalio.DigitalInOut(board.D11)


# Define LCD column and row size for 16x2 LCD.
lcd_columns = 16
lcd_rows    = 2

# Initialise the lcd class---
lcd = characterlcd.Character_LCD_Mono(lcd_rs, lcd_en, lcd_d4, lcd_d5, lcd_d6,
                                      lcd_d7, lcd_columns, lcd_rows)


# Init sensors---
dhtDevice_nutrient_mist = adafruit_dht.DHT11(board.D24, use_pulseio=False)
#dhtDevice_xx = adafruit_dht.DHT22(board.Dxx, use_pulseio=False)
#dhtDevice = adafruit_dht.DHT11(board.D24, use_pulseio=False)


# Define relays
relay_fogger = 21 #digitalio.DigitalInOut(board.D21) #- Why does this not work?
relay_oxygen = 20 #digitalio.DigitalInOut(board.D20) #- Why does this not work?
relay_led    = 16 #digitalio.DigitalInOut(board.D16) #- Why does this not work?


# Init relays---
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setup(relay_fogger, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(relay_oxygen, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(relay_led, GPIO.OUT)


# Define liquid nutrient temperature probe
liquid_nutrients_probe = 16 #digitalio.DigitalInOut(board.D16) - Why does this not work?


# Define the killswitch push button
GPIO.setup(12, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)


# Global variables---
killswitch = False

# Fogger bucket vars
temp_nutrient_solution = 0
temp_nutrient_mist = 0
humidity_nutrient_mist = 0
fogger_on_seconds = 2700 #45 min
fogger_off_seconds = 900 #15 min
sleep_fogger = False

# Grow bucket vars
temp_roots = 0
humidity_roots = 0

# Oxygen bucket vars
sleep_oxygen = False

# Rapsberry Pi internal temperature
rpi_internal_temp = 0


# Methods---
def get_temp_nutrient_solution(killswitch): # Temp  för näringsväska. KLAR för TEST
    """Measure the temperature of the nutrient solution where the ultrasonic fogger is."""
    while not killswitch:
        global temp_nutrient_solution
        temp_nutrient_solution = 22
        #lcd.message = datetime.now().strftime('%b %d  %H:%M:%S\n')        
        #lcd.message = "Dummy temp liquid solution:/n {:.1f}C".format(temp_nutrient_solution)
        # For development process
        print(
            "T: {:.1f} C / {:.1f} F".format(
                temp_nutrient_solution, c2f(temp_nutrient_mist)
            )
        )
        sleep(1)


def get_temp_humidity_nutrient_mist(killswitch): # Temp och fuktighet för ånga. KLAR för TEST
    """Measure the tmeperature and humidity of the nutrient mist where the ultrasonic fogger is."""
    while not killswitch:
        try:
            # Update global temp value and humidity once per second
            global temp_nutrient_mist
            global humidity_nutrient_mist            
            temp_nutrient_mist = dhtDevice_nutrient_mist.temperature
            humidity_nutrient_mist = dhtDevice_nutrient_mist.humidity
            
            # For development process
            print(
                "T: {:.1f} C / {:.1f} F Humidity: {}% ".format(
                    temp_nutrient_mist, c2f(temp_nutrient_mist), humidity_nutrient_mist
                )
            )
 
        except RuntimeError as error:
            # Errors happen fairly often, DHT's are hard to read, just keep going
            print(error.args[0])
            sleep(1) # sleep(1) for DHT11 and sleep(2) for DHT22
            pass
        except Exception as error:
            dhtDevice.exit()
            kill_processes() # Förbättra denna här så att den ska visa vilken DHT-enhet som har fått error
            raise error
     
        sleep(1)


def relay_fogger_control(killswitch, sleep_fogger): # Fogger av eller på
    """Fogger on for 45 min and off for 15. Perpetual mode unless kill_processes() is activated"""
    while not killswitch or sleep_fogger:
        GPIO.output(relay_fogger, GPIO.HIGH)
        sleep(1)
        #sleep(fogger_on_seconds)
        GPIO.output(relay_fogger, GPIO.LOW)
        sleep(1)
        #sleep(fogger_off_seconds)


def relay_heatLED_control(killswitch): # Värmelampa LED av eller på
    """Heat LED controller. When is it too hot for the crops? Sleep interval? Perpetual mode unless kill_processes() is activated"""
    while not killswitch:
        GPIO.output(relay_led, GPIO.HIGH)
        sleep(3)
        #sleep(fogger_on_seconds)
        GPIO.output(relay_led, GPIO.LOW)
        sleep(3)
        #sleep(fogger_off_seconds)

def relay_oxygen_control(killswitch, sleep_oxygen): # Syremaskin av eller på
    """Oxygen maker. Perpetual mode unless kill_processes() is activated"""
    while not killswitch or sleep_oxygen:
        GPIO.output(relay_oxygen, GPIO.HIGH)
        sleep(5)
        #sleep(fogger_on_seconds)
        GPIO.output(relay_oxygen, GPIO.LOW)        
        #sleep(fogger_off_seconds)
        sleep(5)


def kill_processes(): # Döda alla processer
    """ToDo: A button must be pressed which gracefully kills all processes preparing for shutdown."""
    # Power off machines
    GPIO.output(relay_fogger, GPIO.LOW)
    GPIO.output(relay_led, GPIO.LOW)
    GPIO.output(relay_oxygen, GPIO.LOW)
    
    # Joined the threads / stop the threads after killswitch is true
    t1.join()
    t2.join()
    t3.join()
    t4.join()
    t5.join()
    #t6.join()
    
    reset_clear_lcd()
    # Stop message and GPIO clearing
    lcd.message = 'Full stop.\r\nSafe to remove.'
    GPIO.cleanup()
    

def reset_clear_lcd(): # Reset och rensa LCD
    """Move cursor to (0,0) and clear the screen"""
    lcd.home()
    lcd.clear()
    

def get_rpi_temp(): # Reset och rensa LCD
    """Move cursor to (0,0) and clear the screen"""
    global rpi_internal_temp
    cpu = CPUTemperature()
    rpi_internal_temp = cpu.temperature


def c2f(temperature_c):
    """Convert Celsius to Fahrenheit"""
    return temperature_c * (9 / 5) + 32


def lcd_display_data_controller(killswitch): # LCD display data controller
    """Display various measurments and data on the small LCD. Switch every four seconds."""
    while not killswitch:
        reset_clear_lcd()
        
        # Raspberry Pi internal temperature  
        lcd.message = (
            "R Pi (int. temp): \n{:.1f}C/{:.1f}F ".format(
                rpi_internal_temp, c2f(rpi_internal_temp)
            )
        )
        sleep(5)
        reset_clear_lcd()
        
        # Nutrient liquid temperature   
        lcd.message = (
            "F1: {:.1f}C/{:.1f}F ".format(
                temp_nutrient_solution, c2f(temp_nutrient_solution)
            )
        )
        sleep(5)
        reset_clear_lcd()
        
        # Nutrient mist temperature and humidity
        lcd.message = (
            "F2: {:.1f}C/{:.1f}F \nHumidity: {}% ".format(
                temp_nutrient_mist, c2f(temp_nutrient_mist), humidity_nutrient_mist
            )
        )
        sleep(5)
        reset_clear_lcd()

        # Root temperature and humidity
        lcd.message = (
            "R1: {:.1f}C/{:.1f}F \nHumidity: {}% ".format(
                temp_roots, c2f(temp_roots), humidity_roots
            )
        )
        sleep(5)
        reset_clear_lcd()


def button_callback(channel):
    global killswitch
    print("Button was pushed!")
    killswitch = True

# Init the button
GPIO.add_event_detect(12, GPIO.RISING, callback=button_callback)

# Create the threads
#tx = threading.Thread(target=xx, args=(killswitch,sleep_fogger,))
t1 = threading.Thread(target=get_temp_nutrient_solution, args=(killswitch,))
t2 = threading.Thread(target=get_temp_humidity_nutrient_mist, args=(killswitch,))
t3 = threading.Thread(target=relay_fogger_control, args=(killswitch,sleep_fogger,))
t4 = threading.Thread(target=lcd_display_data_controller, args=(killswitch,))
t5 = threading.Thread(target=get_rpi_temp)
#t6 = threading.Thread(target=killswitch_button)
 
 
# Start the threads
t1.start()
t2.start()
t3.start()
t4.start()
t5.start()
#t6.start()

# Code main process---
while not killswitch:
    sleep(1)

# Graceful exit
kill_processes()
```

Comment: Each of the functions that are run by threads (why is `get_temp_nutrient_solution` run by *two* threads?) need themselves to be inside their own `while not killswitch:` loop. You then need something (another thread) to detect your `"two buttons"` condition and set `killswitch = True`. Then your main process can be: `while not killswitch: sleep(1)`.

Comment: You're accessing the LCD from multiple threads, right? What stops two threads from changing the LCD at the same time? You may want to consider having a dedicated LCD thread to display information.

Comment: @quamrana, thank you. I have edited my code according to your suggestion. I have now fixed most of the issue but one. I have updated my questio with the new edition of the code.

Comment: @NickODell, thank you for your suggestion. I have updated my code according to your suggestion.